Samsung C4060FX Issues
I purchased a Samsung printer and have suffered some really bad heat and the Fuser went. I bought a replacement fuser and installed it but the paper stops after feeding into the fuser causing a paper jam. I am now shown that there is a "HDD/Memory" issue also.
To complicate things further I can't for the life of me find what admin password is being used. I haven't ever set a password so I assume it's default. If not I can reset it I just can't see how.
Anything you can suggest would be great.
To summarise:

Reset password
Fuser replacement
HDD/Memory issue (not sure how this happened)


It’s entirely possible the device suffered memory failures due to the unit overheating

It doesn't include your printer specifically, but you could try the steps in this YouTube video: How To Reset To Default All Samsung Proxpress Printers.

Check the paper path in case something melted. It may need some disassembly to gain acess - make sure to take photos as you go in case you need them for reassembly.
